# Using filter on a manytomany through object

Tags: django, django-models

trying to gather a collection of objects:

```
set = [model1].objects.all().filter([model2]__in=[model3].[model2]_set)
```

but I get a

```
TypeError at [url]
'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable
```

when I try to do this. Models 2 and 3 are related via a **ManyToMany** field in Model 2 **through** a fourth model that has both models as fields.

Any obvious workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is in `[model2]__in=[model3].[model2]_set` the correct form would be

```
set = [model1].objects.all().filter([model2]__in=[model3].[model2]_set.all())
```